# Hosting static files in specific directory along React app with routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a `React` (CRA) app which I successfully deploy to `Firebase` hosting by doing:

```
$ firebase deploy
```

Here is the file: `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the content of the root directory:

```
.env
.firebase/
.firebaserc
.git/
.gitignore
build/
firebase.json
node_modules/
package.json
package-lock.json
public/
src/
```

I access the `React` app on the following link:

https://my-project-name.web.app

**What I need** is to configure things around so I can add a new directory on the root of the project, for example: `/files/` where I can access whatever file I have (host) in there, for example:

- https://my-project-name.web.app/files/banner.jpg
- https://my-project-name.web.app/files/document.pdf

and at the same time I should keep accessing the app with same link as above:

https://my-project-name.web.app

Note that the app has routes configured, for example, I can access the following routes in the app:

- https://my-project-name.web.app/users
- https://my-project-name.web.app/users/jessica

That's why I need some kind of exception just for the route: `/files/`.

Thanks!

Comment: [public](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) is probably what you want to be using.

Comment: @abraham you totally right, that works for me. If you post your suggestion as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue trying to add Apple Pay to a Firebase Hosted React app. I needed to host the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Files that should be served without being bundled into the app should be placed in the [`public` directory](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/).

> If you put a file into the public folder, it will not be processed by webpack. Instead it will be copied into the build folder untouched. To reference assets in the public folder, you need to use an environment variable called PUBLIC_URL.